# Pasting values from one dataframe to another after satisfying multiple if conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I am trying to paste a unique value from one dataframe into a newly created column in a separate dataframe. The function requires multiple conditions to be met. In this case both the 'Date' and 'Product' values must be identical in both dataframes.

I have tried for, if and while functions but I cannot seem to crack the problem.

```
sales1 <- data.frame("Day" = c(01,02,03,04), "Product" = c("B","A","D","C"), "salesVol" = c(12,31,3,90))
sales2 <- data.frame("Day" = c(01,01,01,01,02,02,02,02,03,03,03,03,04,04,04,04), "Product" = c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D"), "Price" = c(9,3,4,5,7,10,5,8,4,5,11,3,12,4,7,6))
```

```
for (i in 1:nrow(sales1)){
  if (sales1$Product == sales2$Product
      && sales1$Day == sales2$Day)
  {
    sales1$dailyPrice[i] <- sales2$Price[i]
  }
}
```

Note that there can only be one unique combination of date/product within sales2.

Also tried:

```
while (sales1$Product == sales2$Product
       && sales1$Day == sales2$Day){
    sales1$dailyPrice <- sales2$Price
}
```

The resulting sales1 dataframe should be:

```
Day Product salesVol dailyPrice
1    B        12       3
2    A        31       7
3    D        3        3
4    C        90       7
```

i.e. when the day is 2 and the the product is 'A', the 'dailyPrice' is 7 as per sales2.

However at best I get incorrect values and at worst (above code) nothing gets pasted. No error messages either. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
merge(sales1,sales2,by=c("Day","Product"))
```

Here's everything:

```
  sales1 <- data.frame("Day" = c(01,02,03,04),
 "Product" = c("B","A","D","C"), "salesVol" = c(12,31,3,90))
  sales2 <- data.frame("Day" = c(01,01,01,01,02,02,02,02,03,03,03,03,04,04,04,04),
  "Product" = c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D")
    , "Price" = c(9,3,4,5,7,10,5,8,4,5,11,3,12,4,7,6))
sales1
sales2
merge(sales1,sales2,by=c("Day","Product"))
```

Comment: FWIW, if above is the right answer, this question is probably a duplicate for merging [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560789/merging-two-data-frames-by-key-column)

Comment: This will work, but my original problem has many other variables that unnecessarily get merged, and if there are multiple 'Product' columns then they must be re-merged for each product which will create a ton of excess data. I really need to just target the value that meets these conditions and paste it into a new column in the original dataframe.

Comment: If it's ```sales2``` that has a bunch of extra columns, just subset it. ```merge(sales1, sales2[, c('Day', 'Product', 'Price')], by = c('Day', 'Product'))``` and call it a day.